# SF Workbench - SOAP object properties error

Tags: workbench

After logging into SF via the workbench login screen I'm seeing the below message:

UNKNOWN ERROR: SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no 'uiRequestId' property

I do see that an update was made in github as of a few hours ago, so curious if it has something to do with this. Figured I'd report as I don't see anything else quite like this on the github or here on Stack Exchange.

Comment: I found this old [KI](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008a6HAAQ). It may be that the WSDL is broken again. I'd contact Support.

Comment: [This](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/388438/salesforce-workbench-error-soap-error-encoding-object-has-no-uirequestid-p) is a duplicate.

Comment: It's a bit unfortunate that the later post got all the discussion and upvotes. But this seems to be the first.

Comment: I've reached out to our concerned Salesforce team on this error and will respond as I have more details.

Comment: It appears to be an issue with external instance of workbench and is not in Salesforce scope.  [Workbench doesn't have official external support](https://workbench.developerforce.com/help.php)

Answer (score 3):

Got the same error. Try v56, it worked for me.