# salesforce workbench error : SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no 'uiRequestId' property

Tags: workbench

we are not able to access salesforce workbench today. Getting following error

> UNKNOWN ERROR: SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no 'uiRequestId' property

Comment: Change Settings to V54.0; this error occurs on V55 and V56

Comment: Welcome to new users who've reached this question via search! We're glad to have you on SFSE. Please use the upvote buttons to show your gratitude if this question and answer helps solve your problem - don't leave comments or add duplicate answers. Check out our [tour] to learn more about the SFSE community.

Answer (score 31):

Please use latest version 56.0 and use it. This error shouldn't be thrown with version 56.

Comment: I changed the version in workbench to v56 and the error is gone. Thanks Adrian!

Comment: It was Kameshwar Singh who answered..

Comment: version 50.0 also works around this issue.