# Workbench Error: UNKNOWN ERROR: SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no 'uiRequestId' property

Tags: workbench

I've been receiving this error when trying to use Workbench. I found [this post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/388438/salesforce-workbench-error-soap-error-encoding-object-has-no-uirequestid-p/388441#388441?newreg=718bb55bab3c4a4b905818a9ccf866d7) about using v56 which I'm already using so this didn't solve my problem. Does anyone have any other tips or guidance?

[image]

Comment: Even though it shows I'm using v56, you have to click the little dropdown next to workbench > settings > change version from 55 to 56.

Comment: i got the same error and switching to v54 is working for me.